# Show or Hide HTML DIV in JSF 1.2

Tags: jsf

When the Apache My Faces JSF 1.2 Implementation renders an HTML page behind the scenes , is it even possible to set/code something which will display a pure HTML Table / DIV (NOT the jsf component ) conditionally. When I searched , I saw that , using h:panelGroup is a solution, but I haven't tried yet, posting here for any better methods or approaches.

Its almost like wanting to say - writing a javascript code in java and inject it when the HTML is rendered - is it possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Several ways.

1. Use `<h:panelGroup layout="block">`. It renders a HTML `<div>` element.

   ```
   <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{bean.condition}">
       content
   </h:panelGroup>
   ```
2. Wrap the HTML `<div>` element inside a `<h:panelGroup>`. Without any client-side attributes like `id`, `styleClass`, `onclick`, etc, the `<h:panelGroup>` won't render anything. With them it would however render a `<span>` element (or `<div>` if `layout` is set to `block`).

   ```
   <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.condition}">
       <div>content</div>
   </h:panelGroup>
   ```
3. Wrap the HTML `<div>` element inside a `<f:verbatim>`.

   ```
   <f:verbatim rendered="#{bean.condition}">
       <div>content</div>
   </f:verbatim>
   ```

It's by the way not so special that MyFaces generates HTML. The Mojarra JSF implementation also does that. The competitors Struts2, Spring MVC, Wicket, Tapestry, etc..etc.. also. Microsoft ASP.NET MVC also. PHP also. All server side languages in fact. Simply because of the fact that the webbrowser doesn't understand them. It only understands HTML/CSS/JS ;)

As to mixing JavaScript with Java/JSP/JSF, you may find [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html) useful.

Comment: +1 for the nice explanation of server side languages. I will try these approaches. Thanks.

Comment: Mr @BalusC, I liked your first approach, but problem is `layout` is cannot be resolved in my jsp file. What can be  the reason. I'm using jsf 1.2. Thanks!

Comment: @Jam: it was introduced in JSF 1.2. So you're using JSF 1.1 or your IDE thinks that you're using JSF 1.1. Run the code regardless, check generated HTML in browser, does it work? Then your IDE was wrong. Does it not work? Then you're apparently actually using JSF 1.1.

Comment: What if the text we need to render comes from an EL expression and includes newlines?  Which element can we use inside the `<h:panelGroup>` component that will render text with newline characters?

Comment: @jahroy: newlines are in HTML not represented by `\n` characters at all. Look in the average HTML source code, you'll "see"
 a lot of `\n` characters, but none of them are ever interpreted as such in the HTML presentation by the webbrowser. Search around, I've answered this several times before.

Comment: Thanks.  I know to use `<br />` rather than `\n`... I'll look around for an appropriate question/answer.